# How to get a component from a raycast hit in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using the code function "GetComponent", in reference to a raycast hit but it doesn't work

Basically, in my game the player can use batteries to charge various devices, at the moment I am just trying to get the code for picking up the battery to actually work, but when i use the line

hit.collider.GetComponent(Battery_PickUp_Charge).isheld(true)

I get the error message

'Battery_PickUp_Charge' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Even though that is the exact name of the script/component that is attached to the battery objects, am I missing something. I just want an explanation of what I did wrong, thanks.

P.S Sorry for formatting errors etc. I have never posted on Stack Overflow before

Comment: Same way you get a component from anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the Raycast hits an object you don't get an actual reference to the object back. You get the RaycastHit struct (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html) back, which does contain the information you need to find the actual object back.

```
private void MyRaycastMethod()
{
    Vector3 origin = Vector3.zero;      // insert position
    Vector3 destination = Vector3.zero; // insert position
    
    Ray ray = new Ray()
    {
        origin = origin,
        direction = origin - destination,
    };
    
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit, distance: Mathf.Infinity, layerMask: layerMask))
    {
        // here you get when the raycast hit's an object, but we want a battery:
        if (hit.transform.gameObject.TryGetComponent(out Battery_PickUp_Charge battery))
        {
            // code to handle what to do with the battery:
            battery.isHeld = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked, but also I am silly because I did not declare isheld as a public variable which probably was not helping.... thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think the syntax is wrong.
try this

```
hit.collider.GetComponent<Battery_PickUp_Charge>().isheld(true);
```

Comment: This is it. When specifying types as parameters in C#, it's done in arrows right after the function name (this is called a generic parameter), and not as a normal parameter in parantheses.